# Copy cookie to request header in Apache HTTPD

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm trying to set a request header on all requests going through Apache HTTPD. The value needs to be taken from a cookie attached to the request. From the Apache docs it looks like [mod_headers](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_headers.html) might work.

From the example on that page I put this together:

```
RequestHeader set MyHeaderName "expr=%{req:access_token}"
```

where "access_token" is the name of the cookie value. That sets the header, but the value is coming through empty, so I don't think I have that expression right.

Is there an expression I can use to get the cookie value?

Comment: Which exact version of apache are you using?  The `expr=` syntax is only available from 2.4.10 on.

Comment: Using version 2.4.23.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `expr=%{req:access_token}` will not get you the cookie value, but only a header having the same name as your cookie.  You probably should try to work out something from `expr=%{HTTP_COOKIE}` and extracting the specific cookie value with a regexp.  Maybe this can work (but I'm not sure the regex back reference can be used as the header value):

```
RequestHeader set MyHeaderName $2 "expr=%{HTTP_COOKIE} =~ /(^|;\ *)access_token=([^;\ ]+)/
```

or this (first set the header, then edit it):

```
RequestHeader set MyHeaderName "%{HTTP_COOKIE}" "expr=%{HTTP_COOKIE} =~ /(^|;\ *)access_token=([^;\ ]+)/
RequestHeader edit MyHeaderName "(^|;\ *)access_token=([^;\ ]+)" "$2"
```

If this doesn't work, you might need to add [mod_env](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) to do it, maybe something like this:

```
SetEnvIf Cookie "(^|;\ *)access_token=([^;\ ]+)" MyCookieValue=$2
RequestHeader set MyHeaderName "%{MyCookieValue}e"
```

See also this similar question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645118/using-mod-header-to-change-cookie-domains

Comment: Thanks Tonin, the regexp in the RequestHeader didn't work, but the mod_env solution does the trick.